# Односоставные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Какое из предложений является определенно-личным:
1. Приди ко мне, любезный друг, под сень черемух и акаций.
2. Вьюгами глубокими избы занесло.
3. Долго прислушиваемся и различаем дрожь в земле.
4. Прислушайтесь к голосу весенней музыки.
5. Прошу покорно садиться.

Склоняюсь к тому, что: 1, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: _Ольга: Какое из предложений является определенно-личным.._ === Может, в задании пропущена частица "не" перед словом "является"?

Answer (score 1):

Я не лингвист, так что мой ответ субъективен. Вопрос поставлен так, что следует указать только одно предложение. Тем не менее, я  согласен с тем, что все, кроме второго, являются определенно-личными. В них легко восстанавливаетя значение конкретного лица. Заметим, предложения с глаголами повелительного наклонения Валгина тоже относит к определенно-личным.

(Ты) Приди ко мне, любезный друг, под сень черемух и акаций.
- Здесь стоит глагол повелительного наклонения в форме второго лица единственного числа (ср.: Не гляди же с тоской на дорогу).

(Мы) Долго прислушиваемся и различаем дрожь в земле.

(Вы) Прислушайтесь к голосу весенней музыки.
- Здесь стоит глагол повелительного наклонения в форме второго лица множественного числа.

(Я) Прошу покорно садиться.
- По поводу этот предложения есть у меня сомнения. По смыслу "прошу покорно" — просьба (ср.: Просьба садиться!), а направлена она неизвестно кому. Может быть, данное предложение и нельзя считать определенно-личным.

Информацию об определенно-личных предложениях находим у Валгиной ([49. Определенно-личные предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-023.htm)):

> Главный член в определенно-личных предложениях может быть выражен глаголом в форме первого или второго лица единственного числа изъявительного наклонения: Стою один среди равнины голой (Ес.); Видишь, Алешин, справа огонь? (Бонд.); глаголом в форме второго лица множественного числа изъявительного наклонения (при обращении к собеседнику): Что скажете, Иванов?; реже - глаголом в форме первого лица множественного числа изъявительного наклонения: Будем прорываться к орудиям (Бонд.); глаголом повелительного наклонения в форме второго лица единственного и множественного числа и - реже - в форме первого лица множественного числа (со значением побуждения к совместному действию): Не гляди же с тоской на дорогу, и за тройкой вослед не спеши, и тоскливую в сердце тревогу поскорей навсегда заглуши! (Н.); Грянь над пучиною моря, в поле, в лесу засвищи, чашу вселенского горя всю расплещи! (Н.); Славьте, молот и стих, землю молодости (М.); Начнем, пожалуй! (П.); Пойдем, старик! (Т.). Все эти формы четко передают значение конкретного лица (или лиц), так как эти значения заключены в окончаниях глагола. Именно определенность значений этих форм позволяет включить подобные предложения в разряд односоставных, а не считать их неполными двусоставными с опущенным подлежащим - личным местоимением, так как это личное местоимение не требуется для полноты высказывания, а если и используется (в двусоставном предложении), то является дополнительным средством передачи того же значения.

Если же требуется выбрать только одно предложение, то я бы выбрал третье. Возможно, не все признают предложения с глаголами повелительного наклонения определенно-личными, а по поводу пятого я уже писал выше.

Comment: А почему не все признают предложения с глаголами повелительного наклонения определенно-личными? Лицо определено - я прошу. В школе  точно определённо-личное, а на вузовское задание не похоже. Там если только некоторые товарищи оспаривают, но они и неопр.-личные относят к неполным двусоставным, у них другая классификация.

Comment: @Людмила Значит, прав slava1947: вопрос в том, какое из предложений НЕ является определенно-личным.  И ответ: второе.

Comment: В общем-то, да.   Если отвечать на вопрос "какое?" , то  вопрос некорректен, так как там несколько ответов. Сейчас  так много всяких несуразностей в заданиях, я уже не удивляюсь, пусть ученик спросит учителя, что там имелось в виду. Откуда-то учитель взял это задание, может, и сам придумал.